# Clarification - Dealing with additonal information in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to Backbone and I'm working on a project that is probably not ideal for Backbone really, but I'm trying anyway! I'm not working with a RESTful API, so all of my data is fetched on page load and that is it, it is then not updated, at all. The data is sent through as a single lump of JSON.

I have set up a new model `CookingItem` which gets created for every item in the JSON and is then added to the `CookingItemList` collection, this is fine. However, I need to store information about the data set somewhere so I have created another 'Properties model' that stores this information (state information, start items etc). This properties model will also have several methods that manipulate the data.. these are then called from the view (is this OK?).

This is working fine, but I just want to be sure what I'm doing is considered a good way of doing things. I'm sure there may be a better way to handle the `Properties` model?

```
// Models
var CookingItem = Backbone.Model.extend(),

CookingProperties = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        startItem: 'anything',
        currentItems:[]
    },
    setStartItem:function (val) {
        // Code Here to edit this models properties
    },
    addRemoveItem:function (val) {
        // Code Here to edit this models properties
    }
}),

// Collection
CookingItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:CookingItem,
    url:function () {
        return "json.js";
    }
}),

// View
CookingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'.page',
    events:{
        // Buttons in the UI
        'click .link1':function () {
            this.cookingProperties.addRemoveItem('item name');
        },
        'click .link2':function () {
            this.cookingProperties.addRemoveItem('item name');
        }
    },
    initialize:function () {
        // Scope
        var _this = this;
        // Instantiate
        this.cookingItemList = new CookingItemList();  // PlayListItems Collection.
        this.cookingProperties = new CookingProperties(); // Properties Model.
        // Bindings
        this.cookingProperties.on('change:startItem', function () {
            _this.customMethod1();
            _this.customMethod2();
        });
        // Render the view
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.cookingItemList.fetch({
            success:function () {
                _this.cookingProperties.setStartItem('item');
                _this.customMethod1();
            }
        });
        return this;
    },
    customMethod1:function () {
        // Do something
    },
    customMethod2:function () {
        // Do something
    }
}),

// Start
cookingView = new CookingView({
    collection:CookingItemList
});
```

Comment: have a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: You may want to consider posting this on the [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)